# How to get data of already purchase subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase, in-app-purchase-receipt

**I have implement in app purchase in to my app and I want to get details of already purchase subscription's sku data and currant status.
with this data I want to use for proration and cancel

is there any way to find this**

Comment: May be you need to pass the auth in headers also.